# Angular check authenticate user, before the template is served

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

When the route change, I try to access to /settings

```
 .when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/settings',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
    authenticate: true
  })

.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    Auth.checkUser();
    if (next.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
       $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
```

The code calls to Auth.checkUser() (Asynch) and later to !Auth.isLoggedIn(). The problem is that I need to wait for Auth.checkUser(), that gives me the right status of the user, or find a way to check the response before serving the template.

```
 checkUser: function(user, callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;    
    return User.check(user,
      function(user) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = user.id;
        return cb(user);
      },
      function(err) {
        return cb(err);
      }).$promise;
  },

  isLoggedIn: function() {
    var user = $rootScope.currentUser;
    return !!user;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `resolve` mechanism of angularjs controllers. This way you can define any pre-requisite (service injection, waiting promises, etc) of your controller before render it.

- See angular doc : [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)
- See a working example on angular-app project : https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security

Example :

```
.when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/settings',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
    authenticate: true,
    resolve: {
        isUserLogged: ['yourservice' , function(yourservice) {
            return yourservice.isUserLoggedPromise();
        }]
    }
  })
```

Your screen will be rendered only after (and if) `isUserLoggedPromise` is resolved